# Subscribe a user in MailChimp API V3

Tags: c#, json.net, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We got a problem with adding a member to a list using MailChimp API V3.
Here is our code:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "API Key");

var reply = await client.GetStringAsync("lists");

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListResults>(reply);

AddMembers member = new AddMembers {
                                       EmailAddress = "test@yahoo.com",
                                       Status = "subscribed"
                                   };

string url = "lists/" + list.Data[0].Id + "/members";

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member);
var content = new StringContent(
                    jsonData,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage addMember = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

And this is what MailChimp expects:

```
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/57afe96172/members' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}'
```

But what we get after the below code :

```
 HttpResponseMessage addMember = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

is a 'Bad Request' message with StatusCode '400'. We are really confused, maybe something simple is missing.

Comment: Try to debug it by placing `Console.WriteLine()` statements in parts of your code. For example, what is the value of the `url` attribute before making the POST request? Is that url properly derived?

Comment: The url is generating correctly. We have checked it beforehand. Also the content field ,which is the final JSON being posted, is just like the data that mailchimp is expecting. BTW, because the protocol of mailchimp is https, we can't debug our posted value using fiddler.

Comment: You should post the error response body from MailChimp, it will usually tell you what the problem is. It may be that "test@yahoo.com" is being picked up as a bogus address?

Comment: @TooMuchPete This is the error response, which we can not figure out anything from : {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Request-Id: 792775bd-8ed6-4da5-8a6b-6fa7c6d0753b
  Link: <https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/ProblemDetailDocument.json>; rel="describedBy"
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: close
  Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2015 10:02:26 GMT
  Set-Cookie: _AVESTA_ENVIRONMENT=prod; path=/
  Server: nginx
  Content-Length: 178
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}}

Comment: I see that you figured out this error, but for future debugging, what you posted above isn't the error response. It's an error object javascript generated. The actual error response (the text the server returns) will have a more detailed error message and you should definitely be pulling that out and looking at it first whenever you get an API error you don't understand!

Comment: @TooMuchPete This is what HttpResponseMessage class tells us. since MailChimp API uses https protocol, we can not track what we have sent and what we get as response using Fiddler or the other tools. Would you please give a hand to us to find the error message that server returns? Where should we look for it?

Comment: The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) explains this adequately: the HttpResponseMessage class has a `Content` property that will return the content.

Answer (score 0):

If this is client side JavaScript, that's your problem. MailChimp's API does not support CORS so you won't be able to make API requests from the browser. This is probably a good thing in this case, since sending your API key to a client is giving every visitor to your website full admin access to your MailChimp account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that if you send a duplicate user to MailChimp, they send you a Bad Request error.